# v13.0 starts the node. What is the parameter of RPC

Tags: node, rpc, docker

Upgrade to v13.0 startup node why RPC can not work normally;
my parameters:

`start --rpc-port 8732 --rpc-addr 0.0.0.0:8732 --allow-all-rpc 0.0.0.0:8732`

```
ubuntu@VM-0-16-ubuntu:/data/xtz$ ./mainnet.sh head
Warning:
  Failed to acquire the protocol version from the node
  Rpc request failed:
     - meth: GET
     - uri: http://node:8732/chains/main/blocks/head/protocols
     - error: Unable to connect to the node: "Unix.Unix_error(Unix.ECONNREFUSED, "connect", "")"

Error:
  Rpc request failed:
     - meth: GET
     - uri: http://node:8732/chains/main/blocks/head/header
     - error: Unable to connect to the node: "Unix.Unix_error(Unix.ECONNREFUSED, "connect", "")"
ubuntu@VM-0-16-ubuntu:/data/xtz$
```

Answer (score 2):

That's a known bug. You can track it here: https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/issues/3280

**edit**: original issue
https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/issues/2972

Comment: When will the next version be released